# Is There a Way to Prevent Touch Access to The Parts That Get Covered By PancakeView?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.forms

In the code that I wrote a portion of the screen is covered by a control center on top of a map intentionally. Unfortunately, the map is still accessible from the empty parts of the control center. Is there a way to prevent this?

My .xaml code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:map="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.Maps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Maps"
             xmlns:pan ="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"  
             xmlns:yummy="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="GreenPath.MainPage">

    <Grid>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <map:Map MapType="Street" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <yummy:PancakeView CornerRadius="25,25,0,0" Opacity="0.8" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="White" TranslationY="550">
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5">
                <Image Source="down.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1"/>
                <Label  Text="X" TextColor="#3E454F" FontSize="40" FontFamily="segoeui.ttf" Margin="10,0"/>
                <SearchBar FontFamily="segoeui.ttf" Text="X" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Fill" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalOptions="Fill" SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed" PlaceholderColor="#3E454F" TextColor="#3E454F" CancelButtonColor="#3E454F" Visual="Material" Keyboard="Default" Placeholder="Search a location" IsEnabled="True"/>
                <Label Text="X" FontFamily="segoeui.ttf" FontSize="25" VerticalOptions="Center" TextColor="#3E454F" Margin="10,0"/>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1" ColumnSpacing="0">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="2" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="3" />
                    <Image Source="add.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Scale="1" Grid.Column="4" />
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
        </yummy:PancakeView>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: did you try to use InputTransparent="True" on the pancakeView properties ?

Comment: No it didn't work InputTransparent property didn't have any effect on it.